# User allow to create/update Only Own Post

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post-type(i.e. Company Profile) I want to allow a user to create or update only the Profile they own. How can I do this?

Also is there a hook or method that can be checked to determine if the user is the author of the content or not, if the user has created the content then redirect on edit profile.

Comment: create a user role, that can't edit others post. or check which user roles already has that.

Comment: I've edited the text so it makes a bit more sense in English.

Answer (score 0):

This function might be able to help you.

It checks if the user can edit other peoples post,

and if they can't, only display his/her own posts in the dashboard.

```
/*only allow editors and admin to see all posts.*/
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;
        if( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
            global $user_ID;
            $query->set('author', $user_ID );
        }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

You can play around with a similar approach, to redirect from user profile.